# Change width of embedded google form

Tags: google-forms

I want to embed a google form on my website as an iframe. On high resolution screens the form is too small as google sets a max-width property of 700px on the form container (.ss-form-container). The only thing you can easily change is the dimensions of the iframe but this has no impact on the width of the actual form within it.

I have spent a long time searching for solutions but there is very little relating to this on the web. The few tutorials I have found describe a method where you view your live google form and look at the source code then cut and paste all the code between the 'form' tags straight into your webpage to allow styling with CSS. However, I think that google has since changed the way that forms are displayed and there is no longer a section using the tags 'form' and '/form' when you view the source code for any live form.

Any suggestions as to how I can change this max-width property for an embedded google form will be gratefully received.

My google form can be viewed at:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1TTFzTNuogahyPGDrhqvhDtMxTyY1e4vNYYWl3f8NS78/viewform

Comment: Just go with it.
Add some more stuff to the website and then it will look right. Otherwise go with NetStarter’s answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem,Instead of embedding the form in iframe the solution I tried was to simply

1. Copy paste the complete source code to a new html page saved it on
   my local machine
2. Modified the css.

Answer (score 0):

If someone just like me ends up on this page, here is what worked for me. In the html code (iframe), change the width option to : `width="100%"`

Tested on a laptop and on a phone. Works for form and calendar integration.

Note that if you are using your integration in a multiple columns environment, `width="100%"` corresponds to the column width, so you do not need to change this parameter.

If you need a tutorial, you can check [this one](https://wplift.com/embed-google-forms-in-wordpress/).